# Special Character/Accent Commands and Ligatures in Custom Encoding

Tags: pdftex, accents, font-encodings, ligatures, extended-characters

I have a project I'm working on where I need to define a custom encoding, which I'm calling K7. My question is how I can get commands for special characters to work. In particular:

- `\k{ }` (ogonek)
- `\TH`
- `\th`
- `\DH`
- `\dh`

In my `K7.enc`, I have, for instance, `/thorn` and `/Thorn`. However, if I try to use the command `\th` in a LaTeX document using this encoding, I get the following error

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \th unavailable in encoding K7.
```

I assume there's some extra step that I'm missing that maps these commands to characters in the coding, but what is it? Information is unfortunately scarce.

Also, how do I tell TeX where substitute in ligatures?

Comment: You should take as model the file `t1enc.def` and, based on the slots as set in `k7.enc`, build `k7enc.def` that will be automatically loaded by `\usepackage[K7]{fontenc}`. You will also need `k7enc.dfu` (look for `t1enc.dfu`) for mapping Unicode characters to the corresponding object in `k7enc.def`. Then you need K7 encoded fonts; which I assume you prepare using `k7.enc` as a reencoding vector for `dvips` and `pdftex`.

Comment: As you can see from my answer, this looks like some months' work. `;-)`

Comment: Indeed. However, after several days of trying, I'm finally getting it to work!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that your K7 encoding contains characters that are not available in T1. There are various stages for this.

I'll describe what happens for T1.

### Step 1

We have a Type1 font that contains many more than 256 glyphs. In order to access them, we need an *encoding vector*, a file such as `cm-super-t1.enc` which contains

```
% LIGKERN hyphen hyphen =: endash ; endash hyphen =: emdash ;
% LIGKERN quoteleft quoteleft =: quotedblleft ;
% LIGKERN quoteright quoteright =: quotedblright ;
% LIGKERN comma comma =: quotedblbase ; less less =: guillemotleft ;
% LIGKERN greater greater =: guillemotright ;
% LIGKERN f f =: ff ; f i =: fi ; f l =: fl ; ff i =: ffi ; ff l =: ffl ;
%
% LIGKERN space {} * ; * {} space ; zero {} * ; * {} zero ;
% LIGKERN one {} * ; * {} one ; two {} * ; * {} two ;
% LIGKERN three {} * ; * {} three ; four {} * ; * {} four ;
% LIGKERN five {} * ; * {} five ; six {} * ; * {} six ;
% LIGKERN seven {} * ; * {} seven ; eight {} * ; * {} eight ;
% LIGKERN nine {} * ; * {} nine ;
%
/T1Encoding [
% 0x00
/grave
/acute
/circumflex
/tilde
/dieresis
/hungarumlaut
/ring
/caron
/breve
/macron
/dotaccent
[...]
/oslash
/ugrave
/uacute
/ucircumflex
/udieresis
/yacute
/thorn
/germandbls % or /germandbls.alt
] def
```

This assigns glyphs to slots. You need a map file for doing the reencoding when the font is loaded by `pdftex` or `dvips` with lines such as

```
ecrm1000 SFRM1000 " T1Encoding ReEncodeFont " <cm-super-t1.enc <sfrm1000.pfb
```

where `SFRM1000` is the name of the Type1 font, `ecrm1000` is the corresponding TFM file and `sfrm1000.pfb` is the font file. The TFM file (possibly accompanied by a VF file) can be obtained with `fontinst` or `afm2tfm`.

This map file can be loaded at runtime in `pdftex` via `\pdfmapfile` or with `dvips` with a command line option.

### Step 2

You have to prepare a `t1enc.def` file that assigns LICR to the slots. The file contains

```
\ProvidesFile{t1enc.def}
 [2016/06/19 v1.99m
         Standard LaTeX file]
\DeclareFontEncoding{T1}{}{}
\DeclareTextAccent{\`}{T1}{0}
\DeclareTextAccent{\'}{T1}{1}
\DeclareTextAccent{\^}{T1}{2}
\DeclareTextAccent{\~}{T1}{3}
\DeclareTextAccent{\"}{T1}{4}
[...]
\DeclareTextSymbol{\textvisiblespace}{T1}{32}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\th}{T1}{254}
\DeclareTextComposite{\.}{T1}{i}{`\i}
\DeclareTextComposite{\.}{T1}{\i}{`\i}
\DeclareTextComposite{\u}{T1}{A}{128}
\DeclareTextComposite{\k}{T1}{A}{129}
[...]
```

For instance, `\th` is mapped to slot 254 and the combination `\k{A}` to slot 129 (A with ogonek).

### Step 3

You optionally need a file `t1enc.dfu` for mapping Unicode representations of the characters to the LICR

```
  \ProvidesFile{t1enc.dfu}
   [2016/02/28 v1.1s UTF-8 support for inputenc]
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A0}{\nobreakspace}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A1}{\textexclamdown}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00A3}{\textsterling}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AB}{\guillemotleft}
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00AD}{\-}
[...]
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{00FE}{\th}
[...]
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{0104}{\k A}
[...]
```

so `Ą` will be mapped to `\k A` when the file is read (and `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` is used) and then to slot 129 when the current output encoding is T1.

### Final notes

The preparation of the TFM/VF files mentioned in Step 1 is essential for this to work, because TeX needs them. The information about ligatures and kerning belongs to this stage. The `fontinst` suite has a very extensive manual.

### Conclusion

Use XeTeX/LuaTeX and OpenType fonts.

Comment: This is great. One question though: do the comments in the ``.enc`` file beginning with ``% LIGKERN ...`` actually generate ligatures in the ``.tfm`` file, or is there something else I have to do?

Comment: @KevinKeith They are used by `afm2tfm`.